# Telegram Global Search using the raw API function via Telethon

Tags: telethon

I am trying to use the [SearchGlobalRequest](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/search_global.html) API method for global, full-text search on Telegram, but I am not sure what to use for some of the arguments, especially the `offset_peer` parameter. When I do this:

```
try:
    result = client(SearchGlobalRequest(
        q=search_term,
        filter=None,
        min_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(min_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
        max_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(max_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
        offset_rate=-1,
        # offset_peer=None,
        offset_id=-1,
        limit=10
    ))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I get `__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset_peer'`.

When I try to pass None as `offset_peer`, I get `Cannot cast NoneType to any kind of Peer.` I am not trying to search in any specific channel, I just want to specify the start and end date and find all (or rather as many as possible) matching results.

I am using Telethon version 1.24.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next code works for me:

```
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import SearchGlobalRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputMessagesFilterEmpty, InputPeerEmpty

results = client(SearchGlobalRequest(
    q='your_query_here',
    filter=InputMessagesFilterEmpty(),
    min_date=None,
    max_date=None,
    offset_rate=0,
    offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
    offset_id=0,
    limit=100,
    folder_id=None
))
print(results.stringify())
```

Comment: Thanks, using InputMessagesFilterEmpty and InputPeerEmpty solves my issue.

As a follow-up question, is there a way to paginate the results? I suppose that could be done using offset_id, but what ID should I use there?

Also, in your experience, are the search results complete and reliable? Or is it more of a sample?